# Access to a python array gives Index Error but the array ist defenitivly filled

Tags: python, arrays, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a Problem with my Programm. I want to read a file line for line and split every line into it's word parts and save it into an array. So far so good.
The reading works. The spliting works. The Array is filled. But when i try to get access to any other element then the first i get the "IndexError:list index out of range".
There is no Problem when i print the whole arry. Every element is shown then.

So here is the Code:

```
zieldatei = open('c:\\datacrawler.txt','a')
with open('c:\\Python35\\'+Dateiname,'r') as f:
 for line in f:
  analyser(line)
  if 'SET NAME IS' in line:
   break


def analyser (empfaenger):
 strlaenge= len(empfaenger)
 record = 'RECORD NAME IS'
 stufennummer2 = empfaenger.split()
 #print(stufennummer2)     <------------this is possible
 print(stufennummer2[1])  <-------------this makes problems
 stufennummer = stufennummer2[1]<-------this makes problems 
 typ1 = 'type is binary'
 typ2 = 'pic x' 
 if stufennummer == '01' :
  feldname = empfaenger.split()[2]
  strlaenge2 = len(feldname)
  strlaenge3 = str(strlaenge2)
  zieldatei.write('        77 FN-ST-TAG PIC X('+strlaenge3+')name+'".\n')
```

I have no Idea why i get this Problem. Maybe someone can help me.
Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Keep in mind that python list indices start from 0

Comment: Why do't you show us what `print(stufennummer2)` prints and what exception `print(stufennummer2[1])`produces? The rest is irrelevant.

Comment: print(stufennummer2) prints every Array with the elements of the line. print(stufennummer2[1]) gives me the IdexError

Comment: the program breaks when i try to get Access to a specific element of an array

Comment: the wierd Thing is that i can get Access to the first element (0) but when i try to get accsess to the second (1) or third(2) i get the error

Comment: This is the exact error massage that i get: "IndexError:list index out of range"

Comment: If the list itself has 1 element, this is to be expected, without seeing the actual array itself, though, its impossible to tell if that's the case

Comment: Please show the output of print(stufennummer2).

Comment: You're sure you ran the program with this line `zieldatei.write('        77 FN-ST-TAG PIC X('+strlaenge3+')name+'".\n')` included?

Comment: Also, upon reading your code, there seems to be something missing: when was `zaehler` declared and what value does it hold? Same with `zieldatei`

Answer (score 0):

This is somepart of the print(stufennummer2) out put. it is to big to Show the hole Thing:

```
['R', '*--ROCHADE-GENERIERUNG--*:', 'AM', '06.12.12', 'UM', '08:22:49']
['R', '01', 'IK25-UPD-COUNT', 'TYPE', 'IS', 'BINARY', '31.']
['R', '01', 'IK25-STATUS', 'PIC', 'X(01).']
['R', '01', 'IK25-KTO-ART', 'PIC', 'X(01).']
['R', '01', 'IK25-KTO-ORDN-BEGR', 'PIC', 'X(20).']
['R', '01', 'IK25-PN-LFD-NR', 'TYPE', 'IS', 'BINARY', '15.']
['R', '01', 'IK25-PN-ABRUF-PER-DATUM', 'TYPE', 'IS', 'BINARY', '31.']
['R', '01', 'IK25-FUELLBYTE', 'PIC', 'X(01).']
['R', '01', 'IK25-MUSTER-ART', 'PIC', 'X(01).']
['R', '01', 'IK25-MST-ERST-TM-KEY', 'TYPE', 'IS', 'DECIMAL', '18,0.']
['R', '01', 'IK25-MUSTER-GUELTIG-VON', 'TYPE', 'IS', 'BINARY', '31.']
['R', '01', 'IK25-PN-ABRUF-VERARB-DATUM', 'TYPE', 'IS', 'BINARY', '31.']
['R', '01', 'IK25-PN-BETRAG', 'TYPE', 'IS', 'DECIMAL', '9,2.']
['R', '01', 'IK25-PN-CTV-PRODUKT-MM', 'PIC', 'X(01).']
['R', '01', 'IK25-PN-ABRUF-BETRAG', 'TYPE', 'IS', 'DECIMAL', '9,2.']
['/']
```

Comment: The last array as only one element, so stufennummer2[1] will fail there.

Answer (score 0):

To skip lines which are too short - which is apparently your problem - you could change your code like this:

```
def analyser (empfaenger):
 strlaenge= len(empfaenger)
 record = 'RECORD NAME IS'
 stufennummer2 = empfaenger.split()
 if len(stufennummer2) < 2:
  print('Line too short')
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read a value if it is not there. Skipping lines that are too short
would be one way. Add these lines:

```
def analyser (empfaenger):
    strlaenge= len(empfaenger)
    record = 'RECORD NAME IS'
    stufennummer2 = empfaenger.split()
    if len(stufennummer2) < 2:
         return
    # your code here
```